# Question about the Averson's proof of the bicommutant theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory

In the Averson's proof of the bicommutant theorem is proved that, if $A$ is a self-adjoint algebra of operators with trivial null space and $T \in A''$, for every $\epsilon>0$, $n=1,2..$ and every choice of $n$ vectors $\xi_1, \xi_2,..\xi_n \in H$ there is an operator $S \in A$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^n \|T\xi_k-S\xi_k\|^2 < \epsilon^2$.

The theorem is proved for n=1.

For the general case I copy down a part in the Averson's proof and then I'll ask some questions.

"Now the case of general $n\geq2$ is reduced to the above by the following device.
Fix $n$ and let $H_n=H \oplus H\oplus \ .. \ \oplus H$ be the direct sum of $n$ copies of the undelying Hilbert space $H$. Choose $\xi_1, \ .. ,\xi_n \in H$ and define $\eta \in H_n$ by $\eta = \xi_1 \oplus \ .. \ \oplus \xi_n$. Let $A_n \subseteq L(H_n)$ be the *-algebra of all operators of the form $\{S \oplus \ .. \ \oplus S :S \in A\}$. Thus each element of $A_n$ can be expressed as a diagonal $n \times n$ operator matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
  S & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots \\
  0 & \cdots & S
 \end{pmatrix}

where $S \in A$. The reader can se by a straightforwart calculation that an $n \times n$ operator matrix $(T_{ij})$, $T_{ij} \in L(H)$ commutes with $A_n$ if and only if each entry $T_{ij}$ belongs to $A'$. This gives a representation for $A_n'$ as operator matrices and now a similar calculation shows that $(K_{ij})$ commutes with $A_n'$ if and only if $(K_{ij})$ has the form

\begin{pmatrix}
  K & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots \\
  0 & \cdots & K
 \end{pmatrix}

with $K \in A''$...... etc."

$\ $

I have problem with this part in particular:
"The reader can se by a straightforwart calculation that an $n \times n$ operator matrix $(T_{ij})$, $T_{ij} \in L(H)$ commutes with $A_n$ if and only if each entry $T_{ij}$ belongs to $A'$."

If I have a general operator matrix $T= \begin{pmatrix}
  T_{11} & \cdots & T_{1n} \\
  \vdots  & \ddots  & \vdots \\
  T_{n1} & \cdots & T_{nn}
 \end{pmatrix} $

then to let T commute with $A_n$ it sufficient that $T_{ii}$ belongs to $A'$. It's not necessary that also the other entries that are not in the diagonal belong to $A'$ and this seems to invalidate the second part of the argument about $A''$.

I ask this question because I know that probabily I'm wrong! Can you help me to figure out where?

Comment: You're indeed wrong. Just write the matrix products of $T=(T_{ij})$ with a "diagonal" operator matrix $(K)$: his will give you $(T_{ij}K)$ on the one hand, and $(KT_{ij})$ on the other hand.

Comment: What a stupid error I was doing! I was multiplying term by term, sistematically! Really stupid!

Comment: Don' worry: this happens!

Comment: @Etienne 's' and 't' should exchange their places

Comment: @Norbert I saw 2 "t" missing, but no "s" to exchange with. But maybe you were thinking about something else?